# How to take "access token" value inside an output json file and pass the same "access token" to another REST GET request in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, rest, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, access-token

I have got access token and expiry time as two columns in a JSON file after doing a POST request and stored the file in Blob storage.
Now I need to look inside the JSON file the I stored before and take the value of Access token and use it as a parameter to another REST request.
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario, there are a couple ways you can do this. I assume that you need the access token for a completely different pipeline since you are storing the Get access token output to a file in Blob.

So in order to reference the values within the json Blob file, you can just use a lookup activity in Azure Data Factory. Within this Lookup Activity you will use a dataset for a json file referencing a linked service connection to your Azure Blob Storage.

Here is an illustration with a json file in my Blob container:
[image: JSON Access Token]
[image: Pipeline Illustration]
The above screenshot uses a lookup using the Json File dataset on a Blob Storage Linked service to get the contents of the file. It then saves the outputted contents of the file to variables, one for access token, and another for expiration time. You don't have to save them to variables, and instead can call the output of the activity directly in the subsequent web activity. Here are the details of the outputs and settings:
[image: Lookup Activity Output]
[image: How to call the Access Token from output of previous Lookup activity]

Hopefully this helps, and let me know if you need clarification on anything.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention, if you need to get the access token using a web activity, then just need to use it again for another web activity in the same pipeline, then you can just get the AccessToken Value in the first web activity, and call that output in the next web activity. Just like I showed in the Lookup Activity, but instead you'd be using the response from the first web activity that retrieves the Access Token. Apologies if that's hard to follow, so here is an illustration of what I mean:
[image: Using Access Token in same pipeline]

Comment: It worked using the @activity('Web1').output.access_token. I directly used a Web activity and took the output to a parameter and passed it to the REST request. Got the output and stored the output to blob. Thank You so much.

Comment: Yes, saving to a file was unnecessary... not sure why mine wasn't accepted as answer since it actually showed you don't have to use the file and could instead do directly in same pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to read JSON files into a pipeline is to use the Lookup activity.

1. Here is a test JSON file loaded into Blob Storage in a container named *json*:

[image]

2. Create a JSON Dataset that just points to the container, you won't need to configure or parameterize the Folder or file name values, although you certainly can if that suits your purpose:

[image]

3. Use a Lookup activity that references the Dataset. Populate the Wildcard folder and file name fields. [This example leaves the "Wildcard folder path" blank, because the file is in the container root.] To read a single JSON file, **leave "First row only" checked**.

[image]

4. This will load the file contents into the Lookup Activity's output:

[image]

5. The Lookup activity's *output.firstRow* property will become your JSON root. Process the object as you would any other JSON structure:

[image]

**NOTE**: the Lookup activity has a limit of 5,000 rows and 4MB.